# Show Present and Upcoming days on picker view

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

```
@IBOutlet weak var tvDueDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateText: UITextField!

var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
var dayPicker = UIDatePicker()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

var date_time:String!
var timeAs_24Hour:String!
var selected_date:String!
var timeAs_12Hour:String!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupDatePicker()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func setupDatePicker() {

    datePicker.datePickerMode = .Time
    dayPicker.datePickerMode = .Date

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doneClick))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.cancelClick))

    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    tvDueDate.inputView = datePicker
    tvDueDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    tvDueDate.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    dateText.inputView = dayPicker
    dateText.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    dateText.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}



func doneClick() {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle

    let selected_Final_Date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dayPicker.date)
    let selected_Final_Time = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)

    self.dateText.text  = selected_Final_Date.uppercaseString
    self.tvDueDate.text = selected_Final_Time.uppercaseString

    tvDueDate.resignFirstResponder()
    dateText.resignFirstResponder()
}

func cancelClick() {
    tvDueDate.resignFirstResponder()
    dateText.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

I'm using Swift, and trying to create 2 picker views on 2 text field clicks. On the first text field, it's opening all days month year, on 2nd it's showing timing. I want to show present day and all upcoming days on 1st text field click, and on the 2nd text field, it should show time between 9 am to 6 pm only with a 30min difference like 9, 9:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30.

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a UIDatePicker (or two, if you're determined to select the date in one field and the time in another)

They are designed for **exactly** this purpose.

They have settings they let you determine whether the user can pick dates, or dates and times, or just times. They also have settings they let you limit the range of dates or times that the user can pick. The Xcode documentation is a wonderful thing. You should try it.